# How to listen for string after subdirectory website?

Tags: javascript, html, web, subdirectory

I need to run a JavaScript function when someone goes to https://website.com/custom/U1BJR09U.
The U1BJR09U could be any string, but it needs to be passed on to the function. How should I go about implementing this?

Comment: `location.pathname.split('/')[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all traffic is redirected to a single point that serves a main file handling the URL changes, this should do it:

```
const hasCustom = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/custom\/([0-9A-Z]+)$/);
if (hasCustom && hasCustom[1]) {
    const myString = hasCustom[1];
    /* Do something with myString here */
}
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- `^` starts with`\/` (escaped slash)
- follows with `custom`
- has `\/` (another slash)
- Matches `([0-9A-Z]+)` numbers and uppercase letters
- The string ends after numbers and uppercase letters